# If $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is continuous almost everywhere then it's a Borel function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ a function that is continuous a.e. Prove that $f$ is a Borel function. (If it's not true, suppose it has finitely many continuity).

My try (whenever $f$ has finitely many continuity): L $N=\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ s.t. $f$ is continuous on $S:=\mathbb R\setminus N$. Let $U\subset \mathbb R$ open. Since $f$ is continuous on $S$, then $S\cap f^{-1}(U)$ is an open of $S$. Since $f^{-1}(U)=(f^{-1}(U)\cap S)\cup(f^{-1}(U)\cap N)$ and that $f^{-1}(U)\cap N$ is finite, then, $f^{-1}(U)$ is Borel.

Does this work ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: I edited my question.

Comment: This is false. The function need not be Borel measurable.

Comment: Could you provide an example ? And if it has finitely many discontinuity ? @KaviRamaMurthy

Answer (score 1):

This is false. There is  subset $E$ of the Cantor set $C$ which is  not a Borel set. If $f(x)=1$ for $x \in E$ and $0$ for $x \notin E$ the $f$ is continuous almost everywhere but $f$ is not Borel measurable.

Your argument is correct when there are only a  finite number of discontinuities.

Comment: and if $f$ has on finitely many continuity ?

Comment: @Walace In that case the function is Borel.

Comment: And does my proof work ?

Comment: @Walace Yes, it does work.